# Ubuntu Dual Monitor problem black screen second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

The first monitor displays images, but the second one stays black.
They both show as active, but one of them refuses to display anything.
But screen-shot is showing that the second monitor is working.
The monitor is working perfect in Windows as dual monitor setup.

Every time I try to open setting, the setting window opens on the the second monitor which is all black, so I can't change any setting since I can't see anything on that monitor.

My graphics card is a AMD Radeon R9 380X.

[image: Pic]